# List all Books by Price Range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, group-by, range

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy books. Everything works fine, But I would like to group all of my Books in my Index Page by a Price Range.

Currently I am able to list all of my Books through a Loop, but my code is not very DRY.

**How can I list all of the Books corresponding to a Price Range while keeping my code DRY?**

```
EX of what I need.

Books Under $1 
(.50, .99, .99. .50)

--------------------------

Books Between $1 & $2 
(1.50, 1.99, 1.99. 1.50)

--------------------------

Books Between $2 & $3 
(2.50, 2.99, 2.99. 2.50)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
    @books = @publisher.books.where(:ready => true).order("price")
  end

end
```

**MODELS**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :publisher_id, :price, :ready

end
```

**VIEW**

```
###This works fine, but can be really repetitive if I have books at a high price.

<% @books.each do |book| %>

  <% if 0 <= book.price && book.price < 1 %>
    Books under $1
  <% end %$> 

  <% if 1 <= book.price && book.price < 2 %>
    Books Between $1 & $2
  <% end %$>

  <% if 2 <= book.price && book.price < 3 %>
    Books Between $2 & $3
  <% end %$>

  <% if 3 <= book.price && book.price < 4 %>
    Books Between $3 & $4
  <% end %$>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `price.to_i` to get them grouped properly, and then use a loop to write them all:

```
<% @books.group_by { |x| x.price.to_i }.each do |low_price, books| %>
  <p>
    Books between $<%= low_price %> and $<%= low_price + 1 %><br/>
    (<%= books.map(&:price).join(', ') %>) <br/>
    --------------------------
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 i think this solution is nicer, but why not make a method rather than putting it in the view?

Comment: @dax - I suggested the most ad-hoc solution, since I don't know how this is going to be used anywhere else (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

try a method in your books model:

```
def by_price(low, high)
  self.price.between?(low, high)
end
```

then you could call `books.by_price(0, 5)` and get books between $0 and $5